# Assembly referenced in SSIS 2008 script task not working correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have reference a custom assembly in an ssis script task. The script task apparently works correctly but the assembly (first tested with a console program) doesn't work anymore.
The assembly is supposed to transform a text file to a csv file for further import. Once loaded in the script task the function referenced does create an empty file. Logging did not bring any addtionnal info.

Currently the assembly is strongly named, signed, in the GAC as well as in the DTS\SDK folder of MSSQL server.
Any idea ?

Comment: You need to give more info than that, I suggest pasting the code involved in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the error was in my own assembly. So to summarize the correct and easy way to include and use an assembly file in a ssis script task is :

1. Compile the assembly with the correct framework version (in my case 3.5)
2. Sign the assembly
3. Put the assembly in the GAC
4. Reference the assembly within the script task and add an "imports" directive

Actually putting the assembly in the DTS\bin folder did not produce any difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is why I don't usually like using custom assemblies in SSIS.  In this case, I would write a jig (exe) to call the assembly and change SSIS to call my exe.  In the jig (exe) I would wrap the call to the assembly in a try/catch block.  I would trace the incoming parameters and log any errors to a text file or to the system Event Log.  Usually, this approach gives me enough insight into the real problem (bad param, permission problem, weird data, etc) and a good way to recreate the problem and verify a solution.